# C++ VS2010 Linker error regarding namespace variables

Tags: c++, linker

**MyNamespace.h:**

```
namespace MyNamespace{
    int a
}
```

**MyNamespace.cpp:** some function that uses a

**main.cpp**

```
#include "MyNamespace.h"
```

> ```
> main.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >
> FileNamespace::m_rootDirectoryPath"
> (?m_rootDirectoryPath@FileNamespace@@3V?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@A)
> already defined in FileNamespace.obj
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "struct FileNamespace::FileTree FileNamespace::m_dataFileTree"
> (?m_dataFileTree@FileNamespace@@3UFileTree@1@A) already defined in
> FileNamespace.obj
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are *defining* a global variable (with external linkage) in multiple translation units, which results in duplicate definition errors (since you are violating the ODR).

What you should do, instead, is to *declare* it in the header with an `extern` declaration

```
namespace MyNamespace{
    extern int a;
}
```

and define it in a *single* .cpp file (probably in `MyNamespace.cpp`)

```
int MyNamespace::a;
```

This way, the compiler will create only one instance of this variable in a single object module, and the linker will link all the references to it made in other object modules to this single instance.

It may help you to understand the problem noticing that this is the exact equivalent of *declaring* functions in headers (writing there only the prototype) and *defining* them in a single `.cpp`.

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces are no different from other variables; in your header, you are actually defining the "a", not just declaring it.

In your header:

```
namespace MyNamespace{
    extern int a;
}
```

In one source file:

```
int MyNamespace::a;
```